# Octomap slows down the gazebo simulation, is there anyway to speed up

Tags: gazebo, simulation, octomap, ros-electric, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all: I am working with mobile manipulator in simulations for which I am using ROS electric, gazebo, octomap_mapping (version sometime released in June 2012), and my ubuntu OS is 10.10. Point cloud data for the octomap comes from Kinect sensor. I have noticed that my gazebo simulation is slower as a result of octomap.

for e.g. if I run mobile base in simulation with the help of teleop_keyboard, then without the launch of octomap_server node, it runs ok as expected, however as I launch the octomap_server node and again play with teleop_keyboard then it slows down a lot. Same thing with arm trajectory execution in simulation with or without octomap_server. So gazebo is not an issue, slowness comes from octomap.

Is there anyway I can speed up my simulation while using octomap_mapping for 3D mapping.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60104/octomap-slows-down-the-gazebo-simulation,-is-there-anyway-to-speed-up/) by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 373 on 2013-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using high-density high-framrate data in octomap_server will definitely saturate your CPU. There will be an (expensive) raycast to every endpoint before inserting the ray into the map.

Ideally, you will have a spare core that can be used by just octomap_server, but even then you need to preprocess or throttle your data. Our paper (linked from http://octomap.github.io/) will give you some idea about the performance.

Some steps to take:

- [Throttle](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle) the framerate of the point clouds. There's no need to build maps with 30Hz. 5 or even 1 Hz will be just good.
- Change the octomap resolution (parameter `~resolution`, directly relates to the performance)
- Subsample the point clouds e.g. with a PCL voxel grid so something just below your octomap resolution
- Set the maximum range for rays to your area of interest, e.g. 5m (`~sensor_model/max_range`, directly relates to the performance)
- Set the `~latch` parameter of octomap_server to false, and only subscribe to topics you absolutely need.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on 2013-04-10**:
Thanks Armin!